# New line formatting in ls

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i found that `ls -1` will give output with new lines

however when trying to execute the following

```
echo `recover -s ttlhydnwr -c tphtpsd2<<EOF
      ls -1 *.arc
      exit
      EOF` > logger.log
```

the `logger.log` contains the output in a single line like 
  shown below

```
arch_aceprod_1_130836_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_130837_743034701.arc              arch_aceprod_1_131278_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_131279_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_136607_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_136608_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_140913_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_144278_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_144279_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_163776_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_164783_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_164784_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_180828_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_180829_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_186703_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_186704_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_186710_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_186711_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188497_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188498_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188537_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188538_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188543_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188544_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188546_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188547_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188580_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188581_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188777_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_188778_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_192501_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_192502_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_192549_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_205758_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_1_205759_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170900_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170901_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170902_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170903_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170904_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170905_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170906_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170907_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170908_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170909_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170910_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170911_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170912_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170913_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170914_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170915_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170916_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170917_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170918_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170919_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170920_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170921_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170922_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170923_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170924_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170925_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170926_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170927_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170928_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170929_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170930_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170931_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170932_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170933_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170934_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170935_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170936_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170937_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170938_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170939_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170940_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170941_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170942_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170943_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170944_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170981_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170982_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170983_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170984_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170985_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170986_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170987_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170988_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170989_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170990_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170991_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170992_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170993_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170994_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170995_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170996_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170997_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170998_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_170999_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171000_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171001_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171002_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171003_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171004_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171005_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171006_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171007_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171008_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171009_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171010_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171011_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171012_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171013_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171014_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171015_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171016_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171017_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171018_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171019_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171020_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171021_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171022_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171023_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171024_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171025_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171026_743034701.arc arch_aceprod_2_171027_743034701.arc
```

is there a way to get each filename  in a newline

Comment: Probably you should do `ls -1 *.arc > logger.log`

Comment: im doing ls -1 inside the recover "prompt" but i cant(should not) create any files while im inside the prompt as the prompt is a gateway to another server

Comment: Is the command substitution and echo really necessary? Can't you just execute the command directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo` seems superfluous, and is the one merging the output onto one line. Try:

```
recover -s ttlhydnwr -c tphtpsd2<<EOF  > logger.log 
ls -1 *.arc
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: *I agree with the others with regards to the necessity of `echo`, but in case you need a work around which requires the use of `echo` ...*

This is an ugly hack, but would this work? My thoughts are:

1. First, find all your *arc files and assign it to a variable
2. Edit variable so the charcters "`\n`" replace the spaces
3. Take advantage of `echo -e` option to enable interpretation of backslash escapes (i.e. `\n` becomes a newline)

**Note:** As a substitute for `recover -s ttlhydnwr -c tphtpsd2`, I will use `cat`

```
LS=$(echo $(ls -1 *.arc) | sed 's/ /\\n/g; s/$/\\n/') ; echo -e `cat << EOF
${LS}exit
EOF`
```